# Trouble understanding path.relative

Tags: node.js

You can see in the code below that the parent-parent folder of p1 is a sibling of p2.

```js
> p1 = "/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/src/reducers/testSlice.js"
> p2 = "/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/combineReducers.js"
> path.relative(p2, p1)
'../src/reducers/testSlice.js'
```

So why isn't the final statement `'./src/reducers/testSlice.js'` (one leading period) instead of `'../src/reducers/testSlice.js'` (two leading periods)?

Wouldn't the path it gives, `'../src/reducers/testSlice.js'`, resolve to `test/src/reducers/testSlice.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why isn't the final statement `'./src/reducers/testSlice.js'` (one leading period) instead of `'../src/reducers/testSlice.js'` (two leading periods)?

Because the first argument to `path.relative` is supposed to be the directory that's to be interpreted as the "base" directory from which a relative path to the source is generated. For example, `path.relative('/Users/mike', '/Users/greg')` will result in `../greg`, which is what you expect, right?

Now, you specified a file and not a directory, but node.js can't know that. Assuming `combineReducers.js` is a *directory*, the result makes total sense.

To avoid that, call `path.dirname` on the path first, so the base path will become `/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest`:

```js
> p1 = "/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/src/reducers/testSlice.js"
> p2 = "/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/combineReducers.js"
> path.relative(path.dirname(p2), p1)
'src/reducers/testSlice.js'
```

Comment: Hm ok, so I changed it to `path.relative(path.dirname(reducerFilePath), path.dirname(slicePath))` which gives `src/reducers`, but since I'm actually using this output to plop an `import` statement into a js file, I need it to be `./src/reducers`. Since the relative path could be anything I can't just add on the `./` manually. Is there a way to get what I need?

Comment: You _can_ just prepend `./` because things such as `./../stuff` are valid as well. (Note: this may not be true for Windows if there are different drive letters in play, but for Linux/Mac it should be fine since you should always get a _relative_ path.) Or, you can prepend it only if the path doesn't match `/^\.?\?[/\\]/`.

Answer (score 0):

path.relative [is based on the cwd](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathrelativefrom-to) (current working directory) of each path, which is the final directory of the path.

In this case the final directory in the path is “combineReducers.js” since this is technically a valid directory name. This is why you are seeing the “../“ prefix the result instead of “./“, and also why you see testSlice.js in the output path (testSlice.js is also being treated as a directory)

```
/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/combineReducers.js/
#..
/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/
#../src
/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/src/
#../src/reducers
/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/src/reducers/
#../src/reducers/testSlice.js
/Users/Shared/dev/new-slice-script/src/test/dest/src/reducers/testSlice.js/
```